# add to environment path in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I am trying to add a path to my environment path in vs code. I have this in my settings.json

```json
     "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "Command Prompt": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "args": [
                "C:\\Udvikler\\Launcher\\bin\\jbn16.bat",
            ],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd",
            "path": "C:\\udvikler\\ws\\.npm_packages;${env:PATH}",
        }
    },
```

But the `C:\\udvikler\\ws\\.npm_packages` is not added to the path.

What am I doing wrong?